# Umbraco get node custom property value

Tags: umbraco7

I am trying to get the value of a custom property (isFeatured).  I am working against the current page.

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Macros.PartialViewMacroPage
<div id="featuredpartnerwrapper">
@{       
    var page = Umbraco.TypedContent(1092);
}


@foreach (var child in page.Children) 
{ 
   @child.Name<br />
   @child.GetPropertyValue("isFeatured")
}

</div>
```

the isFeatured property never is rendered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works - but you have to spell the property alias correctly -

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Macros.PartialViewMacroPage
<div id="featuredpartnerwrapper">
@{
    var page = Umbraco.Content(1092);
}

@foreach (var child in page.Children) { 
    @child.Name<br />
    @child.isFeatured
}
```

Comment: PropertyAliases are case sensitive, like most things in .Net and Umbraco